# Ask runtime permission one after another only,not at once in array

Tags: android, permissions, runtime-permissions

In onCreate()of my activity I check for permissions.

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2);
}


if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.CHECK_PHONE_STATE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);

}
```

For every permission,in its callback method I perform certain tasks.So I cannot ask the permissions in array like

```
String[] permissions { };
```

as it will provide me only one call back for all permissions.I perform tasks in every callback in following way.

```
 case ConstantClass.READ_PERMISSION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
              doSomething();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.Cannot_Vibrate_Phone), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;

            case ConstantClass.CALL_PERMISSION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    dialPhoneNumber();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.permission_access_call), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
```

If I ask these permissions one after other in onCreate(). Only the first permission is displayed.So I get only one call back working. So how to achieve the scenario that for every single permission I get a separate call back and call some functions in them. 
Thank you :)

Comment: try to call permission from onpermissionResult

Comment: That could be solution if I have only have couple of permission, what if I have several, then it will mean in every callback I have to check for every permission synchronously irrespective of whether user has accepted or denied it.Can there be a more graceful solution ?

Comment: Do you wish to ask all the permissions one by one or as and when an action related to that permission is performed ?

Comment: @SurajMakhija No,right when an activity starts I need to ask them,basically my permissions are for device id and Ringtone manager.So as soon as activity starts I call the registration api in activty and another api in fragment. So I need to ask them one by one,and they are not interdependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check this Demo Code**

> Ask next permission in response of first permission reject/grant in
>   `onRequestPermissionsResult()`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Context context;
    private static final int REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION_1 = 111;
    private static final int REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION_2 = 222;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = this;
        if (CheckPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            // you have permission go ahead
        } else {
            // you do not have permission go request runtime permissions
            RequestPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION_1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions,
                                           int[] grantResults) {
        switch (permsRequestCode) {
            case REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION_1: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // you have permission go ahead ask next permission and get separate callback
                    RequestPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION_2);
                } else {
                    // you do not have permission show toast.
                    /*check your logic ask again*/
                    //RequestPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION_2);
                }
                return;
            }
            case REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION_2: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // you have 2nd permission go ahead
                } else {
                    // you do not have 2nd permission show toast.
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void RequestPermission(Activity thisActivity, String Permission, int Code) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Permission)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
                    Permission)) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                        new String[]{Permission},
                        Code);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean CheckPermission(Context context, String Permission) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is ok if there are only couple of permissions,but lets say there are many then I need to keep on checking them in every call back for each success and failure and the code will be cyclic.Though this can be one solution.

Comment: yes you have to custom your logic according to your needs.

Comment: @Pritish According to your scenario, the above solution should work fine.

Comment: @SurajMakhija yes it will, but I was looking for a more generic solution,with future phases of my app in view.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the **next permission** in `onRequestPermission` to show permission request **one after another**. You can examine the below code and get the idea. In `onRequestPermissionResult` method:

```
case ConstantClass.READ_PERMISSION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
              doSomething();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.Cannot_Vibrate_Phone), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                // Ask for Camera permission
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CHECK_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
                break;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String permissions[] = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.INTERNET};


    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            &&ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            &&ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, ALL_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    else if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            &&ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {permissions[1], permissions[2], permissions[3]}, ALL_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    else if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {permissions[2], permissions[3]}, ALL_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

This is the best way to get permissions